# How can I prevent vertical scrolling of parent Flatlist when scrolling horizontally in child view?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist with Vertical Scrolling and inside each item of the Flatlist I have a SwipeListView from react-native-swipe-list-view.

Whenever I Swipe horizontally inside the SwipeListView, it gets cancelled if i also start scrolling vertically and then it starts vertically scrolling the Flatlist. I tried using useState to manage the scrollEnabled but this only works when the User slowly slides inside the SwipeListView. With increased velocity there are messed up animations. Also i feel like there must be a cleaner way of achieving this. Anyone know a way to basically disable FlatList scroll while scrolling inside of child component?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, replace react-native-swipe-list-view with [the swipable component that react native gesture handler exports](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/components/swipeable/). This is far more performant as it uses the UI thread to perform all animations. You can then import Flatlist as well from react-native-gesture-handler.

Generally, things should work as is. But if there is any glitchy behaviour you can wrap flatlist with a gestureHandlerRootView and pass RNGH ScrollView to the flatlist renderScrollComponent.

```
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';
import {Flatlist} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

import {
  GestureHandlerRootView,
   PanGestureHandler,
   ScrollView,
 } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default function App(){
   <GestureHandlerRootView>

      <Flatlist renderItem={<Swipeable />}
                 renderScrollComponent={ScrollView}/>
     
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
      
}
```

Comment: Yes that seems to work, however i kind of want to use the swipe-list-view as i have already made a swipe delete animation for it and set it up to work how I want it to. Any idea how to make it work with swipe-list-view?

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing the swipeableRow which can be used to disable scrolling in flatlist.

```
 disableScroll() {
  this.list.getScrollResponder().setNativeProps({
    scrollEnabled: false
  })
}

enableScroll() {
  this.list.getScrollResponder().setNativeProps({
    scrollEnabled: true
  })
}
```

Then in your place of your swipeable component, add this:

```
<SwipeableRow onSwipeStart={disableScroll} onSwipeEnd={enableScroll}  />
```

Also you can try adding this to the FlatList

```
scrollEnabled={false}
```

Comment: Tried this but same thing happens it still glitches the layout, i checked onScroll and onScroll always runs atleast once before the value is changed. Is there maybe a way to cancel the onScroll event if lets say a condition is met?